# TypeError: collection.some is not a function

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-multiselect

```
angular.js:13424 TypeError: collection.some is not a function
at findIndex (angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js:1)
at Scope.$scope.isChecked (angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js:1)
at angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js:1
at Object.forEach (angular.js:321)
at Scope.$scope.getButtonText (angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js:1)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14268), :4:230)
at expressionInputWatch (angular.js:15321)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16860)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17133)
at done (angular.js:11454)
```

Here's the plunker to show the error

https://plnkr.co/edit/SqZGFwf4iD09MqLiisPK?p=preview

So the issue really seems to be with setting value to model where if I set it to an object I see this error. I wanted to have to as single select hence the object instead of an array.

Comment: from where you got this: angularjs-multiselect-dropdown.js file ?

Comment: plunker libraries for angularjs-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: @RakeshBurbure Also I get the same error in my local using https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect

Comment: Yes, having same issue. Its documentation is very poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that what you wanted for first multi select boxes - for them to be single select.
But if you check documentation it's clear that you are missing settings `selectionLimit`, you are right about model being object for one only selection:

```
"model": {
            "id": 1
        },
        "settings": {
            "smartButtonMaxItems": 1,
            selectionLimit: 1
        }
```

New plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/uCBYPG3JCp1v2ECnr6up?p=preview

Forgot to mention, I also updated angular-dropdown-multiselect.js with latest one from github.

Comment: If you would look at the documentation(http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main) you'll see that for "Single Selection Limit" the model needs to be an object and not an array.

The first two dropdown should be single select. By making it an array it becomes multi select.

Comment: sorry I didn't realize that you wanted first two select boxes not to be multi select, I updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the library itself where its checking for array.some event for an Object.

I fixed the issue by adding this check to 'angular-dropdown-multiselect.js'

```
if(toString.call(collection)=="[object Array]")
```